# Which number comes next in the sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

Hopefully people will find this fun and not too easy.

Which number comes next in the sequence?

```
-,-,4,3,6,6,3,13,22,?
```

Comment: What are the first two numbers? Did you mean to not reveal them by putting dashes?

Comment: Yes they are meant to be hidden.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, you should post questions not too often (once or twice a day is fine) so that you can put more effort into making it. You can also combine multiple puzzles into one if they are related :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the last two numbers can be formed by

> $ 4 + 6 + 3 = 13 $ (summing visible number #1, #3, #5)
>  $ 3 + 6 + 13 = 22 $ (summing visible number #2, #4, #6)

My answer for the next number is

> $ 6 + 3 + 22 = 31 $ (summing visible number #3, #5, #7)

This would mean that the first two numbers are the solutions to

> $ a + 4 + 6 = 6 \implies a = -4 $
>  $ b + 3 + 6 = 3 \implies b = -6 $

Comment: Can you also fill in the invisible numbers?

Comment: That means the first and second invisible numbers are Rot13(artngvir sbhe naq artngvir guerr, erfcrpgviryl), assuming you are correct (which I am certain you are) :P

Comment: @user477343 That's not the same thing I got (before or after that stealth edit) :)

Comment: I am glad you noticed, because I was originally wrong, heheh :P

Comment: A very nice answer.